# Pandas: convert column from minutes (type object) to number

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert a column of a Pandas DataFrame from an `object` to a number (e.g., `float64`). The DataFrame is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df
   ID       MIN
0  201167  32:59:00
1  203124     14:23
2  101179      8:37
3  200780      5:22
4  202699       NaN
5  203117       NaN
6  202331  36:05:00
7    2561  30:43:00
```

I would like to convert the `MIN` column from type `object` to a number (e.g., `float64`). For example, `32:59:00` should become `32.983333`.

I'm not sure if it's necessary as an initial step, but I can convert each `NaN` to `0` via:

```
df['MIN'] = np.where(pd.isnull(df['MIN']), '0', df['MIN'])
```

How can I efficiently convert the entire column? I've tried variations of `dt.datetime.strptime()`, `df['MIN'].astype('datetime64')`, and `pd.to_datetime(df['MIN'])` with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining a converter function:

```
def str_to_number(time_str):
    if not isinstance(time_str, str):
        return 0
    minutes, sec, *_ = [int(x) for x in time_str.split(':')]
    return minutes + sec / 60
```

and applying it to the `MIN`column:

```
df.MIN = df.MIN.map(str_to_number)
```

works.

Before:

```
   ID   MIN
0   1   32:59:00
1   2   NaN
2   3   14:23
```

After:

```
   ID   MIN
0   1   32.983333
1   2   0.000000
2   3   14.383333
```

The above is for Python 3. This works for Python 2:

```
def str_to_number(time_str):
    if not isinstance(time_str, str):
        return 0
    entries = [int(x) for x in time_str.split(':')]
    minutes = entries[0]
    sec = entries[1]
    return minutes + sec / 60.0
```

Note the `60.0`. Alternatively, use `from __future__ import print_function` to avoid the integer division problem.

Comment: I'm running in iPython Notebook (via Python 2.7.6 on Mac OS X) and the `*_` in the converter function results in a syntax error: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. How can I get around this?

Comment: @Adam added a version for Python 2.